# More notification sounds not available?

Tags: settings

I have a ONE X and have just reset it to factory default as it was starting to get laggy, I have had 8 Android phones in the last 18 mths ( I have a phone fetish) and all have been HTC except my Galaxy S 2 however when setting up notification sounds on any of my android devices I have always gone to the "Get More" in the notification sound list in settings and a bunch of other sounds are shown and I always d/l "Shooter" as its loud and distinct, however now I click "Get More" it does a search and comes back with "No available content, Tap to refresh", I don't know what I have missed or haven't done this time, yes I have internet connection and when I go through the same procedure in the Ringtone settings it works and I can d/l more ringtones  anyone got any answers other than resetting it again and starting from scratch?

```
                              ------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Would you mind to separate the answer part of your post from the question and put it into the answer section below as its own entry?

Comment: I intended to do that yesterday but at that time the system wouldn't allow me to

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys found the part of the answer myself, hope it helps someone else who has a blonde moment lol although it didn't solve the inability to get more notification sounds through the phone features by hitting the "Get More" button it does allow you to add your own downloaded sounds, a good place to get them is http://www.zedge.net . However if anyone can help with the D/L notification sounds through the phone's "Get More" button issue it would be appreciated.

Change the ringtone, notification sound, and alarm from the Personalize screen.

Choose a ringtone or notification sound from where ever on your PC connect your phone to PC and transfer it to your ringtone folder on your phone,

On your phone slide the Notifications panel open, and then tap > Personalize. On the Sound tab, tap Sound set. Choose a sound set you want to customize (Ring tone, Notification or Alarm), and get your new sound by hitting the + Add at the top of the screen and choosing your new sound and then tap Apply.

All done

HTC One X automatically saves your choices to the current sound set.